# Sticky header delay before sticking on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, sticky

So I've almost finished fiddling with my sticky header, and it's starting to take shape. All the major glitches that I know of have been ironed out. Apart from this one.

When you view [my website](http://burntonionbeta.altervista.org/) (only one page at the moment) on desktop, the header works great, apart from a weird 'bouncing' when using touch which I'll investigate at some point.

**However, when viewing on mobile, there is a noticeable delay before the header sticks/unsticks when scrolling.** I have no idea why this is, and find debugging difficult as my JavaScript experience is close to non-existent. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong?

Here is my sticky code:

```
<script>

// Wrap the logic to a function for call.
var stickFunction = function() {
var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;

function onScroll(e) {
  window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? sticky.classList.add('fixed') :
                                  sticky.classList.remove('fixed');

  window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? jQuery('.content').css("paddingTop", "88.8125px"):
                                  jQuery('.content').css("paddingTop", "0px");
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
}

// Get the image element
var splashImage = document.querySelector('.splash img');

// Check if image is complete or not.
if (splashImage.complete) { // If completed, do the logic.
stickFunction();
} else { // If not, tell the image to call the function for you when it is loaded.
splashImage.onload = stickFunction;
}

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The same problem. Mobile browsers have delays before rerender while scrolling. Had no solution for years.